# Web view is wider than page content in iOS9 Safari

Tags: ios, css, twitter-bootstrap, safari, django-cms

I have a site on Django-CMS and Bootstrap 3, and it has a problem on iPhone - content of the site fits the screen, but I can scroll horizontally and there is a lot of empty space to the right of the content. On desktop safari it works fine.

shrink-to-fit=no in meta "viewport" didn't solve the problem.

Comment: Probably an element is too large. Width or margin or something else. I saw many times similar problems.

Comment: Which exact version of django CMS are you using?

Comment: I use 3.1.3 version, but I've already solve this problem. Germano war right - there was one wide but very short div which I didn't catch at first